# Low disk space issue in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

How does Cassandra solve disk space issues? My disk space is a priority. I'm using the STCS strategy for one table and deleting data via disk monitoring. However, I need to wait for automatic compression to free up space. What's the minimum amount of disk space that's considered insufficient? Is 50% free space necessary? That's too much. If I only want to set 50GB as the threshold for insufficient space, how can I do that?

I'd like to know how to handle low disk space issues in Cassandra. Specifically, if I want to set the threshold for insufficient space to 50GB, what should I do? Ideally, I want this to be handled automatically by Cassandra, rather than manually through operations management.

Answer (score 0):

The 50% disk space for STCS is on the basis of the worst case scenario being 100% of the data needs re-compacting within a major compaction, which can require just as much space for the new files as the existing files are using. This is quite uncommon and it is not unusual to see nodes with the bulk of the tables using STCS to run with less than 50% available.

Cassandra does not have the ability to warn with 50 Gb to go, it will just keep going until there is no space left on the device mounted for the data volume. (Please avoid using more than 1 data directory in the cassandra.yaml, you will cause yourself a lot of pain / performance problems and space usage will get worse, not better).

The "and deleting data via disk monitoring" requires more explanation, that sounds like you are just deleting SSTable files to remove data?

If the data is being aged out with TTLs, then there is the potential of using Time Windows Compaction Strategy. TWCS though comes with some caveats on how the table is used - if you are performing manual deletions / updates, then TWCS is not going to work out well for you.

More information about the table size / usage would be needed to properly consider the compaction options though.

Comment: "Thank you very much. My main question was about how to handle disk space issues using the STCS strategy. Regarding the threshold of 50GB mentioned in the previous question, I added this setting in my code and used disk monitoring to detect insufficient space and execute delete statements while waiting for automatic compression to free up space. What is a safe threshold for me to wait for space to be freed up?"

Comment: Deleted data will not be eligible to be removed from the files until at least gc_grace_seconds have passed, after that point compaction is allowed to drop the data. Lowering the gc_grace_seconds is not recommended since it requires you to repair more frequently. As a table grows, the tombstone rows get trapped in older STCS sstables, so it can take a while and you may need to perform a nodetool garbagecollect or consider LCS which would be more aggressive in compacting.